# ASP.NET MVC ActionLink fora da area

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou com uma dificuldade de fazer uma funcionalidade simples. Eu tenho uma área Chamado "projeto":

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é simples: preciso criar uma Html.ActionLink que gera um link para retornar a página inicial que está FORA da área de projeto, como por exemplo na raiz do site. Tentei chamar assim:

```
 @Html.Action("ACTION","CONTROLLER")
```

Codigo do `controller`:

```
// GET: Relatorio
public ActionResult ModalRelMapaAeronave()
{
    return PartialView("ModalRelMapaAeronave");
}
```

Porém não esta sendo chamada a view correta. Qual a maneira correta de chamar?

Comment: Coloque o código do método do Controller que chama uma determinada `View` !!! Pergunto está chegando na rota?

Comment: Não chega ele, vai numa rola errada, ele soma o valor da area na rota que quero, quando quero chamar a rota direto da raiz.

Comment: `ModalRelMapaAeronave` está em qual `Controller` ?

Comment: A solução do breno deu certo, buscou na raiz. Obrigado galera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para indicar que você não irá acessar uma `Controller` de dentro da sua `area`, indique-a como parâmetro vazio na chamada:

```
@Html.Action("ACTION","CONTROLLER", new { area = "" })
```

Comment: Isso funciona caso eu queira acessar outra area?

Comment: Deu certo para o que eu pedi

Comment: Para acessar outra Area, basta indica-la no parâmetro: @Html.Action("ACTION","CONTROLLER", new { area = "MINHAAREA" })

Comment: Funcionou também obrigado.